# Ordenar elementos por fecha

Tags: java, android, json

Tengo una lista de elementos `JSON` que me llega a través de una consulta y las voy mostrando en un `ListView`:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  ...
  ...
  "created": "2018-11-26 10:26:43"
}
```

Cada elemento tiene una fecha en formato `String`. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es ordenar dicha lista por la fecha, para esto tomé ese `String` y lo convertí a formato `Date`, pero luego de eso no tengo mas idea de como continuar.

¿Es cierto que necesito crear una clase `Model` para esto? ¿o no es necesario?

Agrego el método asíncrono que estoy utilizando:

```
public class listarCiudades extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       ...
       jsonArray = WsClass.ciudadesListaRequest();
       ...
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      super.onPostExecute(s);
      // if(jsonArray.length > 0) {}
      listView.setAdapter(new CiudadesAdapter(context, R.layout.ciudad_item, jsonArray));
      listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
   }
```

En el adapter lo único que hago por ahora es mostar la lista con el Nombre de la Ciudad y la fecha.

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el código que tienes?

Comment: Dónde tenés los datos de ListView, en un List<X> o en un array?

Comment: @Juan Los datos del ListView están en un array. He agregado mi método asíncrono en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la clase de los elementos de la lista?

Comment: @pablo No tengo ninguna clase Model para esos elementos. El Array de la lista se lo paso como parámetro al adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu Array es algo similar a [ idCiudad, nombreCiudad, fecha], siendo la fecha un String aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:

```
//Crear un Stream sobre la lista para ordenarla
        List<String[]> ciudadesOrdenadas = ciudades.stream()
            .sorted(this::ordenarPorFecha)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


//El método que la ordena en base a la fecha

    private int ordenarPorFecha(String[] ciudad1, String[] ciudad2) {
        LocalDateTime fecha1 = LocalDateTime.parse(ciudad1[2], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
        LocalDateTime fecha2 = LocalDateTime.parse(ciudad2[2], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
        return fecha1.compareTo(fecha2);
    }
```

El formateador DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") lo puedes guardar en una variable estática y reutilizarlo, ya que es inmutable y thread-safe:

```
public static final FORMATEADOR_FECHA_COMPLETA = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

private int ordenarPorFecha(String[] ciudad1, String[] ciudad2) {
            LocalDateTime fecha1 = LocalDateTime.parse(ciudad1[2], FORMATEADOR_FECHA_COMPLETA);
            LocalDateTime fecha2 = LocalDateTime.parse(ciudad2[2], FORMATEADOR_FECHA_COMPLETA);
            return fecha1.compareTo(fecha2);
        }
```

Comment: Voy a intentarlo. Tengo una consulta sobre ciudades.stream(). Cual vendría a ser el valor de ciudades?

Comment: Tu lista de tipo List<String[]>

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, hice algunos ajustes e investigué un poco mas en base al código que tengo pero por lo demás me sirvió perfectamente